# MySql INSERT vs PHP file_put_contents

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rapidly growing, write-heavy PHP/MySql application that inserts new rows at a rate of a dozen or so per second into an INNODB table of several million rows.

I started out using realtime INSERT statements and then moved to PHP's file_put_contents to write entries to a file and LOAD DATA INFILE to get the data into the database.  Which is the better approach?

Are there any alternatives I should consider? How can I expect the two methods to handle collisions and increased load in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: One alternative is to write to a secondary table, then do a bulk 'insert into... select from' onto the main table, if writes to the main table are getting to be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `LOAD DATA INFILE` as a batch-method of inserting data. It eliminates the overhead of firing up an insert query for every statement therefore is much faster. However, you lose some of the control when handling errors. It's much easier to handle an error on a single insert query vs one row in the middle of a file.

Comment: You can use the syntax insert into table values (row1),(row2),...,(rowN); to insert as many rows as you want with a single query.  You can also append "... on duplicate key update ..." to specify how to handle unique key collisions

Comment: @atxdba That is a horrible idea on large inserts.

Comment: @feketegy Horrible how?  Performance?  http://tinyurl.com/7jmzbcp  Is SO post laying out how it is better and preferred.  Granted you don't want to load several gigs of data in a single insert but making a blanket undefined statement that it's horrible it is simply wrong. Even mysqldump will create batch inserts by default.  If you're saying for really large sets of data load data can be better, I won't argue that.  I really was just pointing out the available syntax.

Comment: @atxdba It's horrible because of performance issues. It takes up a lot's of memory. Sure it won't affect performance if you use a couple of value groups, but on large inserts it would take forever to insert it in the DB. I would use `prepared statements` or `load data infile` for really large data.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you can afford to have the data inserted by the PHP not being instantly available in the table, then [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) might be an option.

MySQL will accept the data to be inserted and will deal with the insertion later on, putting it into a queue. So this won't block your PHP application while MySQL ensures the data to be inserted later on.

[As it says in the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html)

> Another major benefit of using INSERT DELAYED is that inserts from many clients are bundled together and written in one block. This is much faster than performing many separate inserts.

I have used this for logging data where a data loss is not fatal but if you want to be protected from server crashes when data from `INSERT DELAYED` hadn't been inserted yet, you could look into replicating the changes away to a dedicated slave machine.

Answer (score 0):

The way we deal with our inserts is to have them sent to a message queue system like ActiveMQ. From there we have a separate application that loads the inserts using LOAD DATA INFILE in batches of about 5000. Error handling can still take place with the infile however it processes the inserts much faster. If setting up a message queue is outside of the scope of your application there is no reason that file_put_contents would not be an acceptable option -- Especially if it's already implemented and is working fine.

Additionally you may want to test disabling indexes during writes to see if that improves performance.

Comment: Another point to consider is where the bottleneck for your particular system is. Try using iostat and vmstat to determine where your slowdowns are and where you should focus your efforts. Depending on what you are doing with your data there are many solutions for storage, some of them much faster if not as ACID friendly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you should be using innoDB. Regardless, a dozen inserts per second should not be problematic even for crappy hardware - unless, possibly, your data model is very complex, but for that, LOAD DATA INFILE is very good because, among other things, it rebuilds the indexes only once, as opposed to on every insert. So using files is a decent approach, but do make sure you open them in append only mode.

in the long run (1k+ of writes/s), look at other databases - particularly cassandra for write heavy applications.

Comment: The indexing was on my mind as well.  Which is going to be faster per write - appending to a flat file or inserting to a database?  How would they handle concurrent requests?

Comment: it really depends, you need to run tests and figure it out for your environment. Appending to a file is only atomic if you keep data within a limit (I believe its 4K on linux), o/w you'll have problems with concurrency

Answer (score 0):

if you do go the sql insert route, wrap the pdo execute statements in a transaction. doing so will greatly speed up the process.

Answer (score -1):

`LOAD DATA` is disabled on some servers for security reasons:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.0/en/load-data-local.html

Also I don't enjoy writing my applications upside down to maintain database integrity.